# multiple task in one bash script

Tags: bash, eof

I am trying to execute three tasks in one bash script.

The coding I did is :

```
#!/bin/bash

(cd TRAJ_OctylGlcTryp_C1/
&&
cpptraj zOctylgluTryC1.prmtop << EOF
trajin reImaged-OctylgluTryC1.nc 1 70000 500
trajout reImaged-OctylgluTryC1-500.nc netcdf
EOF 
&& 
cd ../)
```

Which means, first go into directory TRAJ_OctylGlcTryp_C1 and select few frames of simulation data and finally come out of the folder.

But I get error like this

```
./run_Select500Frames.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
./run_Select500Frames.sh: line 4: `&& '
```

Is there any way to get rid of this error?
Thanks.

Comment: What are the brackets supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it more simply this way:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

pushd TRAJ_OctylGlcTryp_C1/ > /dev/null

cpptraj zOctylgluTryC1.prmtop << EOF
trajin reImaged-OctylgluTryC1.nc 1 70000 500
trajout reImaged-OctylgluTryC1-500.nc netcdf
EOF

popd > /dev/null
```

I recommend *always* using `set -eu` at the top of new Bash scripts.  This way the script will stop by itself if a command fails.  From there, I choose to use `pushd` and `popd` as a slightly more reliable way of restoring the old working directory at the end, and the rest is easy.  No more `&&` at all.

Comment: I tried the above script but I get error message: 'EOF': Command not found.

Comment: Make sure you don't have extra whitespace around the EOFs.  I did have one extra space in my answer which I've just removed.  The code works for me.